# git submodule foreach with awk

Tags: bash, git, awk, git-submodules

I'm doing the following to delete all git branches in my submodules, which do not have a tracking reference:

`git submodule foreach "git branch -vv | cut -c 3- | awk '$3 !~/\[/ { print $1 }' | xargs -r git branch -D"`

If I'm executing this without git submodule foreach, it works as expected. But this here results in:

```
awk: cmd. line:1:  !~/\[/ { print  }
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ syntax error
```

I guess there is a problem with the quotes, but I don't get it

Comment: @glennjackman Might want to convert that to an answer so this question gets an accepted.

Comment: FWIW: spotting branches which have no remote : `git branch --format="%(refname:short) %(upstream:short)" | grep -v "origin/[^ ]*$"`

Answer (score 2):

Because of the double quotes, the awk variables are expanded as shell variables (single quotes have no meaning *inside a double quoted string*). Escape the `$` signs: `awk '\$3 ...`

You might want to inject some newlines for readability: a line ending with a pipe continues the pipeline on the next line

```bash
git submodule foreach "
    git branch -vv | 
    cut -c 3- | 
    awk '\$3 !~/\[/ { print \$1 }' | 
    xargs -r git branch -D
"
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, a more direct way of doing this would be

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads \
        --format='%(if)%(upstream)%(then)%(else) git update-ref -d %(refname) %(end)' \
| sh -x
```

which you can safely put in doublequotes as the submodule foreach arg, the f-e-r format and shell scanners nest safely here:

```
git submodule foreach "
        git for-each-ref refs/heads \
                --format='%(if)%(upstream)%(then)%(else)git update-ref -d %(refname) %(end)' \
        | sh -x
"
```

Or alternately

```
git submodule foreach "
        git for-each-ref refs/heads \
                --format='delete %(refname)%(if)%(upstream)%(then) x%(end)' \
        | awk NF==2 \
        | git update-ref --stdin
"
```

(`git update-ref` doesn't like empty commands, can't if-then-else this to remove the awk, grump)